# How do I check if a product is in comparison list magento

Tags: php, magento

You can add product to compare. I have to show the link "Add to Compare" if the product is not  added already otherwise show "Compare". I have to check if the product is in comparison list.

I have `list.phtml` file.

I tried this but this gives all the products added in comparison list.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()
```

I can loop through the returned products and can check if the product is in this collection but I am looking for a single call which take the product `id` or `sku` and return `true` or `false` accordingly.

I also added the filter like this but does not work

```
$_productCollection = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $item->getSku());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Compare_List
```

and its method:

```
getItemCollection
```

Like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_compare_list')->getItemCollection();
$collection->.....Additional filters go here.
```

Why helper didn't worked? Because collection is already loaded there:

v 1.6

```
public function getItemCollection()
{
    if (!$this->_itemCollection) {
        $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')
            ->useProductItem(true)
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_itemCollection->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());
        } elseif ($this->_customerId) {
            $this->_itemCollection->setCustomerId($this->_customerId);
        } else {
            $this->_itemCollection->setVisitorId(Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId());
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        /* Price data is added to consider item stock status using price index */
        $this->_itemCollection->addPriceData();

        $this->_itemCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->load();

        /* update compare items count */
        $this->_getSession()->setCatalogCompareItemsCount(count($this->_itemCollection));
    }

    return $this->_itemCollection;
}
```

So you can load collection by model and filter itself in template or in your own custom helper - model.